DESFire EV1 change key #1 yields Integrity Error after successful auth with AMK #0
It goes like this:

create app with two keys (OK)
select app and auth with key #0 (AMK), EV1 mode, AES/allZerosKey (OK)
communication mode change to Fully Encrypted
ChangeKey command for key #0 (AMK) from AES/allZerosKey to AES/someKey (OK)
reselect app and auth witk key#0, EV1 mode, AES/someKey (OK)
communication mode change to Fully Encrypted
ChangeKey command for key #1 from AES/allZerosKey to AES/someOtherKey (Integrity Error)

Additional info: Key settings are not changed from default values, i.e. to run ChangeKey for any key, auth with AMK needed. Auth always succeeds, even with key#1 AES/allZerosKey. Just the PICC refuses to change key#1 after auth with AMK. It also does it after auth with key#1...
With all that said, what should be my next step to trobleshoot this?
